# Using Vuelidate with v-for and props

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuelidate

How are you all using Vuelidate with `v-for`. I can't seem to get it to work correctly. It either validates each of the `text-fields` in my form, or it throws an error. I only want it to validate the field that is being entered, and not other fields that are created from `v-for`.

In the below template you can see the `creds` in `amazonCredsArray` are props passed in from the parent component. Depending on the number of hashes in the `amazonCredsArray` is the number of forms that are created. With the below setup, the `text-field` below is created multiple times, and Vuelidate validates ALL these fields when just 1 is entered. I have `:key` defined on the field but it doesn't help.

**Template**

```
<template>
<v-container fluid grid-list-lg class="come_closer">
  <v-layout row wrap>
    <v-flex xs12 v-for="creds in amazonCredsArray" :key="creds.id" class="pb-4">
      <v-card class="lightpurple">
        <v-card-title>
          <v-icon class="my_dark_purple_text">language</v-icon>
          <h1 class="title oswald my_dark_purple_text pl-2 pr-5">ENTER YOUR AMAZON CREDENTIALS BELOW</h1>
        </v-card-title>

     <v-form>
        <v-layout xs12 row wrap class="mx-auto" >
          <v-flex xs12>
            <v-text-field
              :error-messages="sellerIdErrors"
              required
              :key="creds.seller_id"
              color="indigo"
              label="Amazon Seller Id"
              v-model="creds.seller_id"
              prepend-icon="person"
              @input="$v.seller_id.$touch()"
              @blur="$v.seller_id.$touch()"
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-flex>
```

And my offending script:

**Script**

```
import { validationMixin } from 'vuelidate';
import { required } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators';

var url = "https://bc-only-rates-trimakas.c9users.io";

export default {
  mixins: [validationMixin],
  validations: {
    seller_id: { required }
  },
  props: ["amazonCredsArray"],
  computed:{
    sellerIdErrors () {
      const errors = []
      if (!this.$v.seller_id.$dirty) return errors
      !this.$v.seller_id.checked && errors.push('Please provide us your seller id')
      return errors
    },
  },
```

Comment: How did you fix this?

Comment: I would also really like to know!

Comment: I have yet to figure out how/if this will every work!